# Plotting a specific dataset in a .h5 file

Tags: plotting

I have a directory that contains 30001 `.h5` files. The files are sorted based on the names. Each `.h5` file contains 4 different datasets. I want to do a loop over all `.h5` files and take one value of a specific dataset and put them all in a list. So in the end, there should be an array of `30001` numbers.

Currently, I have a list of all sorted `.h5` files. However, I do not know how to access a specific dataset in a loop and put them in a list.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. To make this question concrete, please load `3` of those files with `4` datasets each. You can use the zip or an alternate format and use an online drive such as Google drive etc. Make sure the link is public and the file is 1-click downloadable. Thanks.